# command error when running python package

Tags: error-handling, command

Hi I am trying to run a python package called minpower via the command, when i run it get the following error, but i dont understand what this means, so I can not fix it. Could you please tell me what is the meaning of this error ?

Many thanks, Stack1

```
C:\Users\Me>minpower uc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\minpower-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 2837, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 451, in _build_mas
ter
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 464, in _build_fro
m_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 639, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pandas==0.16

C:\Users\Me>
```